# How to optimize a SQL query that combines JOINs and WHERE clause?

Tags: sql

```
SELECT af.* 
  FROM allotissement_flux af  +
  JOIN signature sig 
    ON sig.id_flux = af.ID 
   AND sig.date_statut_signature >= sysdate - 100 
  JOIN stockage stock 
    ON stock.id_flux = af.ID 
   AND stock.date_statut_stockage >= sysdate - 100 
  LEFT 
  JOIN archivage arch 
    ON arch.id_flux = af.ID 
   AND arch.date_statut_archivage >= sysdate - 100 
 WHERE sig.statut_signature = 'A_SIGNE' 
   AND stock.statut_stockage = 'OUI'
   AND ( arch.id_flux IS NULL 
        OR ( arch.id_flux IS NOT NULL 
           AND ( arch.statut_archivage IS NULL 
              OR arch.statut_archivage != 'A_ARCHIVE'
               ) 
         AND arch.statut_disponible_pour_sma != 'OUI'
         AND arch.nb_tentative_archive < 10 
           )
       ) 
   AND rownum <= 10;
```

The query above returns me 4222 rows, and it runs locally in 1.3 seconds. I'm wondering if it is as fast as it can be or if I can tweak it further somehow, as this dataset will grow fast overtime.

Things that I've tried without change in speed:

1 - Change the join order, joining from the smallest to the biggest table.

2 - Adding an index to af.id_flux.

Comment: It looks like you're passing in the parameter `:nbMaxFichier` - could you do the same with the `sysdate` call you are making for each join? The `JOIN` conditions are evaluated for *every* row so this function is being called thousands of times

Comment: So, what is `+`?

Comment: Please provide query plans. Focus on ONE database (sql server) and provide execution plan. 1.3 seconds sounds ridiculously slow - but could be ok if you have a lot of data and did not put sensible indices up. Which we will see on your execution plan. I would rather expect queries like this to take way less than 100ms. You do have beginner mistakes (like text in statut fields that you use to filter, string comparisons are ridiculously expensive) but that should no t be i"it".

Comment: + my head hurts

Comment: Which DBMS, Oracle? `sysdate` is not a builtin T-SQL function. Your syntax is not valid, `+` and missing operand for `AND arch.statut_disponible_pour_sma !=`.

Comment: @Luke:  Every decent optimizer will evaluate `sysdate` once and then used it like a hardcoded value.

Comment: @Ipromise . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.  This is particularly important for questions about performance.